# Where's the loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this code:

```
function filterVencimientos ($arrayFull) {
    $filtered = array_filter($arrayFull, 'month');
    var_dump($filtered);
    return $filtered;
}

function month ($var) {
    $response = false;
    if (is_array($var)) {
        foreach ($var as $item) {
            $response = month($var);
        }
    } else {
        $date = date('Y-m');
        $response = (stripos($var, $date) !== false);
    }
    return $response;
}

function getFiltered () {
    $arrayFull = getVencimientosPorPerfil();
    $arrayFiltered = filterVencimientos($arrayFull);
    return $arrayFiltered;
}
```

And that returns this:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 4194304) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\miramonteapp\api\yscript.php on line 244
```

I'm trying to go through this array:

```
array(1) {
  [258]=>
  array(9) {
    ["recaudacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-07"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-07"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-13"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-13"
    }
  }
}
```

Where's the loop that's causing the out of memory error?

Comment: `foreach ($var as $item){ $response = month($var); }` You're using `$var` instead of `$item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is inside the `foreach` in the `month()` function:

```
$response = month($var);
```

You should be running the `month()` function on the `$item` variable.

Here's what the poor compiler is trying to do:

1. `month()` is called with an array as `$var`
2. Loops through all the elements of `$var`
3. Calls `month()` with the *exact same* argument as was passed in.
4. `month()` is called... etc.

Step 4 is the same as step 1, so the compiler valiantly keeps trying to run your code, which is just running the same function over and over again :'(

Comment: So, what would be the correct way to write the code to achieve my goal?

Comment: i want to get this: `array(1) {
  [258]=>
  array(9) {
    ["recaudacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-07"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-13"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: that is, filter everything except the current month

Comment: @MetaCode I think all you need to do is change `month($var);` to `month($item);`